# Run Excel VBA code using PHP

Tags: php, excel, vba

I created Excel VBA code to create images from the corresponding URLs.

How can I write this code while creating the Excel file using PHP?

```
Sub RetrieveImage()

    Dim url_column As Range
    Dim image_column As Range

    Set url_column = Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns("D")
    Set image_column = Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns("J")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To url_column.Cells.Count

      With image_column.Worksheet.Pictures.Insert(url_column.Cells(i).Value)
        .Left = image_column.Cells(i).Left
        .Top = image_column.Cells(i).Top
        image_column.Cells(i).EntireRow.RowHeight = .Height
      End With

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

You need only for this example or for all many macros ?

If only for this one: Use GD Library to generate image in PHP

If you want to convert macros to php code - that is almost impossible. You will need to write parser, which will translate macro code to php code...